# Is it possible to give any user the right to execute JPS in cmd?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, jvm

[image]

I need this as a normal user (no admin rights), is it possible to give all users the right to execute JPS?

Comment: Normally if you are going for a deliverable there is no need of jdk to execute a java application. JRE is sufficient to execute your java applications. JPS will be in jdk not in jre. So you don' have to worry about he jps permission. Instead you are packaging jdk with your deliverable executing permission will not be harmful since if you block jps there are other ways to grep your java process.

Comment: I have no problem running the application (starts with javaw ...) but I wrote a batch file to kill the application (using JPS to get the process ID and taskkill to kill the process using the process ID). It works fine when I am admin but when I am a regular user, JPS is not known by the command line so it doesn't kill the application.

Comment: Do you mean `jps` cannot be run at all, or it can be run, but does not list all Java processes?